# PostgreSQL Query With Sub-Query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

On my production server, this query returns no results, so I took it to SQLFiddle to test the results with test data to see if maybe it was a conversion issue.  Well SQLFiddle throws an error anytime I attempt to run this query which leads me to believe that the issue is with my syntax.

Using the subset sample data listed below, I want to return `userID & Name` from my table named `blue` where the users title is `like '%Manager%'`  (I have also tried to use `is ILIKE '%Manager%')`This is sample DDL that returns no results but if you look at my sample data you can see that I should have these two results returned:

```
1 Bob
3 Mike
```

However, my query returns 0 results.  What do I need to edit in order for my query to return relevant results?

```
CREATE TABLE blue(
  userID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL, 
  name text NOT NULL   
);

CREATE TABLE RED(
  userID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  ,title text NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO blue (userID, name) VALUES
 (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Joe'), (3, 'Mike'), (4, 'Sam'), (5, 'Bridge');
 INSERT INTO RED (userID, title) VALUES
 (1, 'Manager'), (2, 'Field Operator'), (3, 'Manager II'), (4, 'CFO'), (5, 'New Hire');
```

And this is the query I tried to run

```
Select *
FROM blue
where userID IN (SELECT userID 
                 FROM RED
                 WHERE title ILIKE '%Manager%')
```

This works fine on SQL Server, but it will not work on my PostgreSQL install (which is where my database resides). I was getting the "Something went wrong" error.

Comment: Does it help if you give your table aliases? Maybe the two similar attribute names confuse the engine

Comment: This works for me.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/67b85/1/0  . What error are you getting?

Comment: This works just fine. There must be something you are not telling us.

Comment: Perhaps it's the missing statement terminator that's causing the issue? (`;`) "Something went wrong" does not look like a Postgres error message anyway.